# How can I connect to a URL in a desktop Windows application Installer?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, http-request

I want to verify online if the installer can proceed. If I can change the website to whatever I need, is there any way to make this verification in a WiX generated MSI for a desktop app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a WiX Custom Action to check it and added it to the  `After="FindRelatedProducts"` in the `InstallUISequence` tag

Answer (score 0):

I would get the WiX installer source code and check how it was developed.

Comment: The WiX installler has not implemented this feature yet. Implementing this is the whole purpose of this question.